# Почему не работает register_shutdown_function()?

Tags: php

Точнее даже здесь две проблемы, не работает как надо `register_shutdown_function()`, зарегистрированная функция не пишет ничего в файл, и функция которая в ней вызывается тоже, отправка емеила тоже не срабатывает, работает только echo. И `error_get_last()` возвращает `NULL` даже когда я её запускаю вне функции

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (error_reporting() & $errno)
    {
        $errors = array(
            E_ERROR => 'E_ERROR',
            E_WARNING => 'E_WARNING',
            E_PARSE => 'E_PARSE',
            E_NOTICE => 'E_NOTICE',
            E_CORE_ERROR => 'E_CORE_ERROR',
            E_CORE_WARNING => 'E_CORE_WARNING',
            E_COMPILE_ERROR => 'E_COMPILE_ERROR',
            E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'E_COMPILE_WARNING',
            E_USER_ERROR => 'E_USER_ERROR',
            E_USER_WARNING => 'E_USER_WARNING',
            E_USER_NOTICE => 'E_USER_NOTICE',
            E_STRICT => 'E_STRICT',
            E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
            E_DEPRECATED => 'E_DEPRECATED',
            E_USER_DEPRECATED => 'E_USER_DEPRECATED',
        );
        $msg = date('Y-m-d h:i') . " - {$errors[$errno]}[$errno] $errstr ($errfile in $errline string)\n";
        file_put_contents('error.log', $msg, FILE_APPEND);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

function fatal_error_handler()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error && $error['type'] & ( E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR)) {
        ob_end_clean();
        error_handler($error['type'], $error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
    } else {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}


error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
ob_start();
set_error_handler("error_handler");
register_shutdown_function('fatal_error_handler');
```

Comment: Я думаю у вас проблемы с управлением вывода `ob_`

Comment: Возможно. Но функция должна запустится? Если я делаю так `function fatal_error_handler()
{
    file_put_contents('1.log', '1');` то должно сработать?

Answer (score 0):

используйте полные пути, а не относительные, потому что меняется корневая директория

Comment: лучше давать более развернутые ответы